# Could Printer Friendly Version Of Thread Be Provided?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is it possible to add a print button and provide a printer friendly version of all questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There [already is a printer-friendly stylesheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36709/printer-friendly-button) (with `media="print"`), so I don't think a button will be added. However, it could always be improved, and indeed, [someone created a website that uses the Stack Exchange API](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) to create even [more friendly pages](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/export?format=HTML&question=141&service=meta.wordpress.stackexchange).

This site belongs to [the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/), you can find [a lot of discussion about similar topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printing) on the main meta site.

Comment: I recommend StackPrinter too ;)